# How to using array_diff for both arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP class and want to compare the data using two arrays according like the code below.

But, here I want to show out the difference data of both arrays.

I have tried the code below but it is not working and I'm stuck of this.

```
<?php
class TestClass{
    public $fool = 'hehe';
    public $fool2 = 'huhu';
    public $fool3 = 'haha';
    public $fool4 = 'haha';

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->fool;
        return $this->fool2;
        return $this->fool3;
        return $this->fool4;

    }

}


$arr1 = array();
$class = new TestClass;
$class ->fool='one day';
$class ->fool2 ='test';
array_push($arr1,$class);

$arr2 = array();
$class2 = new TestClass;
$class2 ->fool ='one day';
$class2 ->fool2 ='different test';
array_push($arr2,$class2);

echo print_r($arr1).'<br/>';
echo print_r($arr2).'<br/>';
$result=array_diff($arr1,$arr2);
print_r($result);



?>
```

Comment: Show the expected outcome.

Comment: Only the first `return` statement of function `__toString()` does something. The other two are dead code (they never execute).

Comment: `$class ->fool;` is a no-op (no operation). It gets the value of property `$fool` of object `class` (that have type `TestClass`) then it doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: Read the documentation of [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). Maybe they bring you the idea.

Comment: Oh,thanks,can you show me something that correct one because i'm new on the php class.

Comment: I have changed it be a same class,so,glad if any of you can rectify my code to be correct :)

Comment: Hmm... you better start by reading a book about [`OOP`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/oop/info) and the [chapter about OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing things too much, just to fix your code even if I disagree with your goal and way you do that:

```
class TestClass{
    public $fool = 'hehe';
    public $fool2 = 'huhu';
    public $fool3 = 'haha';
    public $fool4 = 'haha';

    public function __toString()
    {
        return '1: '.$this->fool.'; 2: '.$this->fool2.'; 3: '.$this->fool3.'; 4: '.$this->fool4;
    }

    public function asArray()
    {
        return array($this->fool, $this->fool2,$this->fool3,$this->fool4);
    }
}

$arr1 = array();
$class = new TestClass;
$class ->fool='one day';
$class ->fool2 ='test';
$arr1[]=$class;

$arr2 = array();
$class2 = new TestClass;
$class2 ->fool ='one day';
$class2 ->fool2 ='different test';
$arr2[] = $class2;

echo $arr1[0]."\n";
echo $arr2[0];
print_r($result);

$result=array_diff($arr1[0]->asArray(),$arr2[0]->asArray());

print_r($result);
```

Comment: thanks,your code is help me a lot,it's working right now :cheer: :)

Comment: Sir, if i use loop how it can hold full hold array?
for example :
`for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) {
   $class = new TestClass;
    $class ->fool='one day';
    $class ->fool2 ='test';
    $class ->fool3 ='kahkahkah';
    $arr1= $class;
   $array1 = $arr1->asArray();
  // echo print_r($array1)."<br/>";  //instead like this
   
   
}
 echo print_r($array1)."<br/>"; `

Comment: I don't understand what do you need... :-(  `$arr = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) { 
 $class = new TestClass; 
 $class ->fool='one day'; 
 $class ->fool2 ='test'; 
 $class ->fool3 ='kahkahkah'; 
 $arr[] = $class->asArray(); 
 
} 
echo print_r($arr)."<br/>";` tell me your goal, what do you need to get as result?

Comment: Sorry for that,i mean that i'm using your fixed code above and want to changes a bit into looping for get more array as i comment above.  
 As expected result I want hold all array when echo  at looping outside. :-)

Comment: as expected result show like this because my project will call data from database. <br/> 
`Array ( [0] => one day [1] => test [2] => kahkahkah [3] => haha )`  <br/>
`Array ( [0] => one day [1] => test [2] => kahkahkah [3] => haha )`  <br/>
`Array ( [0] => one day [1] => test [2] => kahkahkah [3] => haha )`  <br/>
`Array ( [0] => one day [1] => test [2] => kahkahkah [3] => haha )`  <br/>
`Array ( [0] => one day [1] => test [2] => kahkahkah [3] => haha )`  <br/>
`Array ( [0] => one day [1] => test [2] => kahkahkah [3] => haha )`

Comment: so `for ($x = 0; $x <= 5; $x++) { $class = new TestClass; $class ->fool='one day'; $class ->fool2 ='test'; $class ->fool3 ='kahkahkah';  echo print_r($class->asArray())."<br/>"; }";`

Comment: I have created a new question,maybe it more be clear there. :cheer: :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285717/php-how-to-hold-all-array-at-outside-of-loop-using-array